# Javascript Boolean.prototype.toString() unexpected results

Tags: javascript, boolean

Working through [Mozilla's Javascript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) using my browser console. Looking at Boolean objects. I've come across an unexpected behaviour with the following method:

> **Boolean.prototype.toString()**
>   Returns a string of either "true" or "false" depending upon the value of the object. Overrides the Object.prototype.toString() method

If I instantiate a boolean true or false they both return the same "false" from this method:

```
var t = Boolean(true);
var f = Boolean(false);

Boolean.prototype.toString(t);
> "false"
Boolean.prototype.toString(f);
> "false"
```

I understand I can more reliably query the object with:

```
Boolean.prototype.constructor(t);
> true
Boolean.prototype.constructor(f);
> false
```

So what I'm asking is: can anyone explain, preferably with examples, **why** *Boolean.prototype.toString(true)* returns false?

Is there a inheritance issue, or is it a bug? Am I not getting something? I've tested this with Boolean Object wrappers, Boolean literals and expressions. I've reproduced this behavior on three browsers on Mac, is this a platform issue? Any help understanding this behaviour would be gratefully received.

Comment: Not sure I get it, `Boolean.prototype.toString()` returns false, why would it return something else when you pass a boolean as an argument ? If you want a string do `t.toString()` or `Boolean.prototype.toString.call(t)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever's on `Boolean.prototype` gets passed along to all booleans. That means that `true.toString === Boolean.prototype.toString`, and doing `true.toString()` is like doing `Boolean.prototype.toString.call(true)`.

When you call `Boolean.prototype.toString` directly, `this === Boolean.prototype`. Looking at [the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.6.4.2), we can see that it attempts to do a conversion in case you get a Boolean object (remember, `Boolean.prototype` is quite literally the prototype of every boolean - it's a boolean object):

> 1. Else if Type(B) is Object and the value of the [[Class]] internal property of B is "Boolean", then let b be the value of the [[PrimitiveValue]] internal property of B.

[[PrimitiveValue]] is essentially a `valueOf` call:

```
Boolean.prototype.valueOf(); //false
```

And `Boolean.prototype` is defined in the spec ([15.6.4](http://es5.github.io/#x15.6.4)) to be the Boolean object `false`.

In summation, what happened here is that instead of trying to call `toString` on the variable you intended, you instead called it on `Boolean.prototype`, which produces the same result every time.

Solution: Don't do that. Call `toString` on the variables: `t.toString()`, `f.toString()`

N.B. You don't need `Boolean(true)` or the likes; just `true` will do.

Answer (score 2):

`Boolean.prototype.toString()` returns "true" or "false" based on the value of the object its called *on*, not *with*.

So you get these expected results:

```
> var t = Boolean(true);
undefined
> var f = Boolean(false);
undefined
> t.toString();
'true'
> f.toString();
'false'
> Boolean.prototype.toString.apply(t);
'true'
> Boolean.prototype.toString.apply(f);
'false'
```

Comment: I get it now, thanks, is there a hole in the documentation? If there is I'm going to edit the Mozilla page? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/toString

Comment: No! There is no hole in the docs, the prototype is not generally what you use when you want to use a method on an object, so you never really do `Boolean.prototype.constructor(t);`, as that works exactly nowhere with nothing

Comment: @TonyCronin The documentation is fine. `Boolean.prototype.toString` refers to the `toString` property of booleans all over. `Boolean.protoype` just happens to be one of them.